# how to calculate the ratio between the most recent month data to the closest data in previous months in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I would like to calculate for each id, the value of var1 in the most recent month, divide by the value of var 1 in this id that is most close to the value in this month. In the example dataset, that means, for id=1, I want to calculate var2=71/43 for month Nov; for id=2, I want to calculate var2=1234/516 for month Jan. How do I do it in Rstudio?

thanks,

lydia

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach for your issue. Please next time do not include images of your data, just use `dput()` and paste the output in your question. Based on your issue you want to compute a ratio for the las month in each group, according to the closest month. Initially, your data is in format year-month. You have to transform it in order to manage dates. You can use as trick computing the differences between the value in last month with the remaining month and filtering the min difference which is not less than or equal to zero. With that you will get the other component for your ratio. Here the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
#First mutate the date
df %>% mutate(date=as.Date(paste0(month,'-','01'),'%b-%Y-%d')) %>%
  #Identify max date and value by group
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value=var1[date==max(date)]) %>%
  #Compute the difference between values
  mutate(diff=value-var1,diff=ifelse(diff<=0,NA,diff)) %>%
  #Mutate to obtain the min as this is the closest value
  mutate(Den=var1[which(diff==min(diff,na.rm=T))[1]]) %>%
  #Now filter the max date
  filter(date==max(date)) %>% select(-c(value,diff,date)) %>%
  #Compute ratio
  mutate(Ratio=var1/Den)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
     id month     var1   Den Ratio
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Nov-2019    71    43  1.65
2     2 Jan-2020  1234   516  2.39
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), month = c("Jun-2019", 
"Jul-2019", "Aug-2019", "Sep-2019", "Oct-2019", "Nov-2019", "Aug-2019", 
"Sep-2019", "Oct-2019", "Nov-2019", "Dec-2019", "Jan-2020"), 
    var1 = c(3, 516, 0, 43, 423, 71, 4231, 12, 516, 0, 2616, 
    1234)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution using `lapply`, which produces a list of one answer per ID

```r
lapply(split(df$var1, df$id), function(x) {
  tail(x, 1)/(head(x, -1)[which.min(abs(head(x, -1) - tail(x, 1)))])})

#> $`1`
#> [1] 1.651163
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2.391473
```

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
      2L, 2L), month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 
      7L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Aug-19", "Dec-19", "Jan-20", "Jul-19", 
      "Jun-19", "Nov-19", "Oct-19", "Sep-19"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(31, 
      516, 0, 43, 423, 71, 4231, 12, 516, 0, 2616, 1234)), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df
#>    id  month var1
#> 1   1 Jun-19   31
#> 2   1 Jul-19  516
#> 3   1 Aug-19    0
#> 4   1 Sep-19   43
#> 5   1 Oct-19  423
#> 6   1 Nov-19   71
#> 7   2 Aug-19 4231
#> 8   2 Sep-19   12
#> 9   2 Oct-19  516
#> 10  2 Nov-19    0
#> 11  2 Dec-19 2616
#> 12  2 Jan-20 1234
```